# How to avoid gray border after scaling an image with transparent pixels

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, image-scaling

When I use waifu2x model to scale an image with transparent pixels, the transparent black background seems to bleed into the image. Using [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) also has this problem.

[image: before]
[image: after]

As specified in [this blog](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/01/scaling-images-with-alpha/), the transparent background can be filled with color as near as context as possible.

It's simple to find borders of such transparent borders. But is there any algorithm to generate such background?

Comment: You can specify what the color must be for transparent pixels. I don't know what software you are using or what file format even. For example GIF and PNG have a value for the background that you can set. The alternative is to find all transparent pixels, and change their value to white.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I understand your solution. But what if the non-transparent part is black? The white color of transparent pixels will still bleed into black parts.

Comment: Make the transparent pixels be whatever color you intend to compose the image on. Then it'll look natural. If you need to be able to compose on arbitrary backgrounds, you would need to do something quite complex, to extend the color of the foreground into the new semi-transparent areas. Maybe it would suffice to interpolate the alpha channel normally, but for the RGB channels to take the color of the opaque neighbor, rather than interpolate. Not sure, never tried this.